# ARM Gdb break on processor mode change

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, arm

Im currently debugging Linux ARM kernel, and have always wondered if it is possible in gdb to break when the cpu mode change (usr, svc, abt etc). Currently, when i'm not sure which mode we are in, I usually have to look at the psr register multiple times, but maybe there is a more effective way, such as break on mode change?

I know I can put breakpoints on the exception vector, but that means I only detect mode changes to privileged mode and not the other way around. Maybe there is a command to check if the psr changes to 0x10(usr mode) ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to break on the switch, or just find out if you're currently running in user or kernel space? If you only need the later information you can just look at your current pc, everything above 0xC0000000 is kernel-space in a default 3/1G split.

Comment: I wan't to run the linux kernel and break when it switches to user mode so i can examine the scheduled user process. Hmmm i could put a break on the scheduler maybe, but problem is kernel processes are scheduled the same way i think

Answer (score 0):

All processes are scheduled in [entry-common.S](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S;hb=HEAD).  This file has a macro named `arch_ret_to_user`.  Define it to be a `BKPT` instruction, perhaps conditional on a global set via `/proc`.

You can not detect a switch to user mode generically using the CPU alone (you need support code), as the supervisor code can change **anything**. [**ETM**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/DDI0344.pdf) may have some means if your CPU has the functionality.

There are also [thread_nofity.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/include/asm/thread_notify.h) which has call-backs for when a user task is re-scheduled.  You can hook this with your own logic if you don't need the debugger or put some *breakpoint* on a `null(){}` function which you only call from the notifier when the condition is meant.